# Testing external AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

Is there anyway to do E2E testing with AngularJS on an external application? Meaning we want to be able to run the Karma test runner on a Windows and a Linux machine to test an application located at http://externaldomain.com (on a different machine)

All of the examples I have seen have their applications hosted on the same server/domain as Karma (localhost), this is not an option for us, and we want to see if we can convert from using Selenium tests to E2E with the Angular DSL but this is becoming a problem with us since it looks like Karma / E2E doesn't support this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of the total details of dependencies..

But the part of JS or angular.js you can obviously test as we test anything in browser, almost anything on browser can be tested, except the services provided by server,

The server side JavaScript if not required to be tested, you can surely do it, Firebug with Mozilla Firefox will be one of the best option..

If your requirement is something else, please let me know more details and dependencies of your application..

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add

```
proxies: { 
    '/' : 'http://externaldomain/'
},

urlRoot: '/_karma_/',

proxyValidateSSL: false,
```

to your karma.conf.js file